# how to control number of rows in plone dexterity form text field?

Tags: forms, plone, dexterity

I'm using Plone 4.2 (autoform 1.3.2) and can't seem to control the number of rows in my dexterity form text field. i see that autoform 1.4 and above allows you to do it directly in the schema like so:

```
    siteAddress = schema.Text(
    title=_(u"Physical Address of Surrendered Site"),
    rows = 10,
    required=False,
)
```

is there anyway (other than through customizing the CSS) i can control this in AF 1.3.2?

Comment: If you say that autoform 1.4 does allow you to do so, why not upgrade to it?

Comment: i'd upgrade but i'm building this on existing code (that was not mine), and i was hoping to avoid any other conflicts that could arise with upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [plone.directives.form](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.directives.form) for this:

```py
from my.package import MessageFactory as _
from plone.directives import form
from plone.supermodel import model
from zope import schema


class IMyType(model.Schema):

    form.widget('text', cols=80, rows=10)
    text = schema.Text(
        title=_(u'Text'),
        default=u'',
        required=False,
    )
```